# Using numpy from the host OS for a spark container

Tags: python, docker, numpy, apache-spark

I want to use the Docker image with Apache Spark on Ubuntu 18.04.

The more popular image from the hub has [Spark 1.6](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/spark). 
The second image has a more recent version [Spark 2.2](https://hub.docker.com/r/p7hb/docker-spark/)

No image has numpy installed. The basic examples for Spark [MLlib main guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-statistics.html) require it.

I've tried running Dockerfile for installing numpy unsuccessfully, adding this to the original Dockerfile for Spark 2.2 image:

```
RUN apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

How do you set the container to use the OS's numpy installation? What is the procedure? Is this the correct direction at all?

Edit: OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: pip install numpy?

Comment: @atline in the dockerfile doesn't work i.e. *RUN pip install numpy* .

Comment: What's the error when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Fully works on my side, see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM p7hb/docker-spark

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y python-numpy
```

**Build command:**

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

**Run container:**

```
docker run -it --rm my_image /bin/bash
```

**Check numpy:**

```
root@55ce4c59122c:~# python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> print(numpy.__version__)
1.12.1
```